# Multiple states being Pareto Optimal

Tags: game-theory, pareto-optimality

### Assuming we a 2 player game and each of them have 2 options. So there are 4 states and each of them have the same payoff. So in such a case, how can we say that all of the states as Pareto Optimal ?
Based on my reading, Pareto Optimality requires that at least one of the players prefer one outcome strictly more than the others, which cannot be the case here.

### | (1,1)  | (1,1) |

### | (1,1)  | (1,1) |

Comment: [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency): *Pareto efficiency or Pareto optimality is a situation where no individual or preference criterion can be better off without making at least one individual or preference criterion worse off.* What have you read that says there must be at least one player preferring one outcome more than others?

Comment: I was wrong in understanding the text,  @kaya3 descriptions solves it.